# Understanding the advective/diffusive behavior of a PDE with mixed derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following PDE:

$$
\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}=D \frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial x^2}+\frac{D}{c} \frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial x \partial t}
$$

where $D$ and $c$ are constants. If the term on the far right is neglected, the equation describes ordinary diffusion with a diffusivity of $D$. If the term on the far left is neglected, the equation describes advection with a celerity of $c$.

I solved this equation numerically with a sine wave initial condition and periodic boundary conditions. I found good agreement between the observed celerity of the numerical solution with $c$. However, I found that the observed diffusivity is often far lower than $D$ (I calculate the diffusivity from the exponential decay in the amplitude of the sine wave). If I make $c$ very large, the observed diffusivity approaches $D$.

I'm wondering why the mixed derivative term, in addition to adding an advective component, also appears to add anti-diffusion, making the diffusivity lower than my naive expectation.